# Getting the value via AJAX, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function with three parameters. The first parameter holds the url that the ajax function go to when it's called. The second parameter contains the id name of the div containing the eventual output. The third parameter contains a variable that can be stored in POST to be sent to the url that the ajax function go to when it's called, so that it can be echoed, and sent to the div with the id 'output' on the original page.

My question is: Are there any ways to get the value in the input type submit, so that it can be stored in POST to be sent to the url that the ajax function go to when it's called, so that it can be echoed, and be seen in the div with the id 'output' on the original page?

So the value in the input type submit would be "submit".

**test1.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function ajaxPass(gotoUrl,output,input) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { input : input },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = "ajaxPass('test2.php','output','input')">
<div id = 'output'> </div>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php

$input = $_POST['input'];
echo $input;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood, but I'll try to answer this part:

> Are there any ways to get the value in the input type submit

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = "ajaxPass('test2.php','output',this.value)">
```

The key is to use `this.value`, `this` referencing the input element, and `value` its, of course, value.

---

See this simple example to see it in action:

```html
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit value here" onclick = "alert(this.value)">
```

---

UPDATE

This example will read the value of the text input element and pass that as `input` variable in the AJAX call:

```
function ajaxPass(gotoUrl,output) {

      var input = document.getElementById('t').value; // or $('#t').val();

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { input : input },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
           }

      });

}

</script>

<input type="text" id="t">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" onclick = "ajaxPass('test2.php','output')">
<div id = 'output'> </div>
```

Comment: Okay. What if I want to have an input type text, and when you press enter, you get the value of the input type text via AJAX?

Comment: Same thing, enter simulates a submit (usually just in case there is only one other input element). The best way to do it would probably be to put an `onsubmit` listener on the form element, and read the text input value from the callback function, no need to pass it in directly.

Comment: Huh...I don't think I understand. This.value gets the value of the tag that it's in right? So if the ajax function is in the form tag, wouldn't it get the value of the form if it has one?

Comment: I would understand a lot better if you provide a few example codes.

Comment: You are correct, that's why I said not to pass the value in, but read it inside the function, like `document.getElementById('textElementIDHere').value`. I'll show you in an update.

Comment: Or, is there a way to reference tag names? Like submit.value?

Comment: "submit" is not a tag name, but an attribute value here.

Comment: I see. This is very, very good. Is there a way for me to replace onclick, with something like onEnter?

Comment: Absolutely, it will work with whatever event you want. If you want to listen to the enter key, you can use the `onkeyup` listener, but ideally you'd make a form element and use the `onsubmit` listener on it (making sure it returns false in order not to actually submit the form).

Comment: Okay. I'm going to search that up. Thanks for your help, man. You were a great help today. I'm going to accept your answer now.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Good luck with AJAX!